# Blackberry - How to use notification icon in statusbar

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, integration, notifications, rim-4.6

In RIM Blackberry OS 4.6+ there is a new feature - ability to show notification icon in statusbar. Integrated application use it to give quick and informative information for user: Dealler - missed calls, Messages - unread messages etc.

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Possible use of notification icon:

- missed events
- RSS updates
- object status (ex. weather/app activity/gps signal strength)
- other

I would like to post a howto guide for this feature.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### ApplicationIndicator class

To add/modify/remove notification icon we can use [ApplicationIndicator](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationIndicator.html) class:

> Represents an application indicator that consists of an icon and optional numeric value.
>   The icon is placed in indicators area along with others such as new mail counter, calendar reminders, missed calls counter, security status and others.

- Application can register only one indicator and has to register it every time the phone starts.
- All indicators are cleared upon phone restart.
- Indicators may be not visible if there will be no space on statusbar
- Indicator dimensions depend on current theme and phone screen size.
- The icon size varies from 10x10 up to 24x24.
- If indicator is initialized with a big icon then an exception is thrown.
- Indicator can have optional numeric value that usually serves as a counter.
- The value can be negative, 0 or positive.
- If indicator is used as a counter it's better to hide it when its value is equal to 0.
- If indicator value is too big, it will display '99+' or '999+'

### Add notification icon

For this we should create instance of [ApplicationIcon](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationIcon.html):

> Application icon class is used in conjunction with application indicator and application messages.
>   It incapsulates image and its painting properties.

```
EncodedImage mImage = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("indicator_icon.png");
ApplicationIcon mIcon = new ApplicationIcon(mImage);
```

Then we should register ApplicationIndicator with [ApplicationIndicatorRegistry](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.html):

> ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.register(*icon*, *iconOnly*, *visible*)
>   *icon* - an icon to be displayed in the indicators area
>   *iconOnly* - specifies if indicator should have icon representation only and no value
>   *visible* - specifies whether indicator has to be visible initially

```
ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
ApplicationIndicator indicator = reg.register(mIcon, false, true);
```

### Modify indicator icon and value

To modify icon, use [ApplicationIndicator.setIcon](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationIndicator.html#setIcon(net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIcon)) method:

```
ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
ApplicationIndicator appIndicator = reg.getApplicationIndicator();
appIndicator.setIcon(icon);
```

To modify number value, use [ApplicationIndicator.setValue](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationIndicator.html#setValue(int)) method:

```
ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
ApplicationIndicator appIndicator = reg.getApplicationIndicator();
appIndicator.setValue(value);
```

- If very big value is provided then indicator will display '99+' or '999+'.

To hide or show indicator, use [ApplicationIndicator.setVisible](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationIndicator.html#setVisible(boolean))

### Unregister ApplicationIndicator

Most likely you don't want your app indicator to stay in statusbar, it's better to [ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.unregister()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.html#unregister()) it on app close.

### Sample application

Icons:

*removed dead ImageShack links*

Screenshots:

*removed dead ImageShack links*

Code:

```
import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIcon;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIndicator;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIndicatorRegistry;
import net.rim.device.api.system.EncodedImage;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Menu;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

class Scr extends MainScreen {
    EncodedImage mImageGreen = EncodedImage
            .getEncodedImageResource("bb_icon_green.png");
    ApplicationIcon mIconGreen = new ApplicationIcon(mImageGreen);
    EncodedImage mImageRed = EncodedImage
            .getEncodedImageResource("bb_icon_red.png");
    ApplicationIcon mIconRed = new ApplicationIcon(mImageRed);

    ApplicationIcon mIcon = mIconGreen;

    public Scr() {
        add(new LabelField("Use menu to:"));
        add(new LabelField("Register indicator"));
        add(new LabelField("Increment value"));
        add(new LabelField("Decrement value"));
        add(new LabelField("Switch icon"));
        add(new LabelField("Unregister indicator"));
    }

    MenuItem menuRegister = new MenuItem("register", 0, 0) {
        public void run() {
            registerIndicator();
        };
    };
    protected int mValue = 0;
    MenuItem menuIncrement = new MenuItem("increment", 0, 0) {
        public void run() {
            mValue++;
            updateValue(mValue);
        };
    };
    MenuItem menuDecrement = new MenuItem("decrement", 0, 0) {
        public void run() {
            mValue--;
            updateValue(mValue);
        };
    };
    MenuItem menuSwitchIcon = new MenuItem("icon", 0, 0) {
        public void run() {
            mIcon = (mIcon == mIconGreen) ? mIconRed : mIconGreen;
            updateIcon(mIcon);
        };
    };
    MenuItem menuUnregister = new MenuItem("unregister", 0, 0) {
        public void run() {
            unregisterIndicator();
        };
    };

    protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
        super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
        menu.add(menuRegister);
        menu.add(menuIncrement);
        menu.add(menuDecrement);
        menu.add(menuSwitchIcon);
        menu.add(menuUnregister);
    }

    private void registerIndicator() {
        try {
            ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry
                    .getInstance();
            ApplicationIndicator indicator = 
                    reg.register(mIcon, false, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private void unregisterIndicator() {
        try {
            ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry
                    .getInstance();
            reg.unregister();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    void updateValue(int value) {
        try {
            ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry
                    .getInstance();
            ApplicationIndicator appIndicator = 
                    reg.getApplicationIndicator();
            appIndicator.setValue(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    void updateIcon(ApplicationIcon icon) {
        try {
            ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry
                    .getInstance();
            ApplicationIndicator appIndicator = 
                    reg.getApplicationIndicator();
            appIndicator.setIcon(icon);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```