# BlackBerry - Is it possible to change the status of the BlackBerry messenger programatically?

Tags: blackberry, contacts, bb-messenger

Is it possible to change the BB Messenger's status programatically? As of now I could just find how to get contacts from the BB Messenger instance.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Blackberry Messenger](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/blackberrymessenger/package-summary.html) package in the API there doesn't appear to be any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set BB Messenger status, but you can register your own application status indicator:
[SO - Blackberry - How to use notification icon in statusbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465224/blackberry-how-to-use-notification-icon-in-statusbar)