# BlackBerry - show info when status bar is pulled down (like 'droid Notification Area)

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, notifications, integration, message

Thanks to Max Gontar, I can put my notification icon in the status bar on 4.6 and up ([Blackberry - How to use notification icon in statusbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465224/blackberry-how-to-use-notification-icon-in-statusbar)).

But in later versions (6 I think?) one can click on the status bar and it will drop down with info on latest calls, App World updates etc.

[image]

This is similar in some ways to the 'droid Notification Area. What classes / methods should I be looking at to implement this kind of info, so I can add my own section to this drop-down area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry` and `ApplicationMessageFolder` classes, and the `ApplicationMessage` and `ApplicationMessageFolderListener` interfaces.

Comment: Could you please help with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952223/blackberry-you-currently-have-no-new-notifications) issue?