# Run BlackBerry application on startup, and add notification that it is running in the background

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to write a Java BlackBerry application that runs on startup and stays running in the background, but gives the user an indication that it is running with an icon in the corner of the homescreen.  What techniques can I use?

Answer (score 2):

For showing content on the home screen / status bar, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330940/blackberry-how-to-add-content-to-the-home-screen-today-plugin). You can either have different states on your own application icon or add a notification in the BB status bar. All is explained there.

Answer (score 1):

right click on blackberry project ->properties->applicaiton tab

1. keeps in background: create Appliation type project.
2. blackberry application that runs on startup:check option "autorun on startup".
3. but gives an indication that it is running with an icon in corner:
   which corner you are talking about?

Comment: corner of BB screen, or other discreet indication that program is running.

Comment: For that i think @Tamar has pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The blackberry button sits to the left of the trackball/trackpad, or to the left of the return button on the storm.   If you press and hold the blackberry button, the OS will show all running apps in a popup.  Do you need a more significant notification that the app is running?

The notification ribbon and the app 'splat' are generally used to show message counts and other activity of interest to the user, not just that your app is running.