# start and close an app depending if battery is being charged or not

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

I want to create a simple Blackberry app that plays an audio file whenever I charge my phone, and for the application to close when I unplug it.

**Pseudocode**

1. Start application when battery cable plugged in,
2. <s>application plays sound continuously while charging</s>

   could not make it loop without a gap of silence in between, instead play a sound
3. if user unplugs cable, stop the stream, play a sound, stop the stream
4. optional: if battery level falls to critical/done charging, play a sound

Looking through the docs I think there isn't a listener to tell you if battery is at 100%.

**Edit**: Found a way through batteryStatusChange, and thanks Nate for helping me out there

Having null exception errors.

**Edit**: Used InputStream and no more null exception errors. Added wav files to the res folder. New code below plays a sound at 100 and two different sounds, one for USB connect and another for USB disconnect.

```
public class HelloBlackBerryScreen extends MainScreen implements SystemListener2 {
    private BasicEditField basicEditField;
    private Player HEV;    
    private String wav;
    private InputStream stream;
    private int volume; //going to set volume from GUI using a drop down list, working on it currently

public HelloBlackBerryScreen() 
{
    super( MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR );
    setTitle( "HelloBlackBerry" );
    add(new RichTextField("Battery", RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_HCENTER));

    Application.getApplication().addSystemListener(this);
    
    wav = "voice_on.wav";
    stream = (InputStream)this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + wav);               
    try {
        HEV = Manager.createPlayer(stream, "audio/wav");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MediaException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void batteryGood() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public void batteryLow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public void batteryStatusChange(int status) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ((status & DeviceInfo.BSTAT_LEVEL_CHANGED) != 0)
    {
        if(DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel() == 100)
        {
            try 
            {
                setWav("power_level_is_100_percent.wav"); 
                HEV.start();
                stream.close();
            } 
            catch (MediaException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               

        }               

    }
}   

public void powerOff() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public void powerUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public void backlightStateChange(boolean on) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public void cradleMismatch(boolean mismatch) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public void fastReset() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public void powerOffRequested(int reason) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public void usbConnectionStateChange(int state) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (state == USB_STATE_CABLE_CONNECTED) 
    {           
        try 
        {
            setWav("suitchargeok1.wav"); 
            HEV.start();
            stream.close();
        } 
        catch (MediaException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        
        } 
        else if (state == USB_STATE_CABLE_DISCONNECTED) 
        {
            try 
            {
                stream.close();
                setWav("battery_pickup.wav"); 
                HEV.start();
                stream.close();
            } catch (MediaException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
}

public String getWav() {
    return wav;
}

public void setWav(String wav) {
    this.wav = wav;
    stream = (InputStream)this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + this.wav);
    try {
        HEV = Manager.createPlayer(stream, "audio/wav");
        HEV.realize();
        VolumeControl volume = (VolumeControl) HEV.getControl("VolumeControl");
        volume.setLevel(25);
        HEV.prefetch();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MediaException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean onClose()
{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestBackground();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: do you really want your app to have any graphical user interface at all, or could it purely be a background app that only plays sounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd need a little more clarification on how you want the app to work (see my comment below your question), but I'm pretty sure you're going to need to implement a `SystemListener` (actually, a `SystemListener2`, which is a kind of `SystemListener`) to listen for USB state changes.

Something like this to detect the connection:

```java
void usbConnectionStateChange(int state) {
   if (state == USB_STATE_CABLE_CONNECTED) {
      // start playing your sound
   } else if (state == USB_STATE_CABLE_DISCONNECTED) {
      // stop playing your sound, and exit, or just stay in the background
   }
}
```

[Here is a link on how to add/register a System Listener on device startup](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/832062/How_To_-_Write_safe_initialization_code.html?nodeid=1487426&vernum=0)

[See this BlackBerry forums link on detecting USB connection](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Differentiate-between-blackberry-connected-to-PC-and-connected/td-p/1333397#M176448)

[And the API docs on SystemListener2, too](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/SystemListener2.html#usbConnectionStateChange%28int%29)

**Update:** as I believe the poster already figured out (based on the code update in the question), the `public void batteryStatusChange(int status)` method is probably the more direct callback to use here.  Everything else is the same, though, as that's just another callback in `SystemListener`.

Comment: Hi Nate, a background application would do. What about a code for detecting if phone is charging or not? This thread below shows how to do that, but I'm guessing its more appropiate to use systemListener2 ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214231/blackberry-determine-if-using-external-power

Comment: Also, in order to implement this, I must start a background app after I restart the phone? Is there a way to start it like the "display clock option when charging"

Comment: @user1615805, that link you posted (with answer from Mister Smith) looks fine.  However, that is just code to **ask** whether the device is charging.  You really need **notification** when charging starts or stops, which is a little different.  In general, charging occurs when USB connection is made, right?  I guess if the phone is 100% charged, it can be connected without currently charging.  If you want, you can implement the `SystemListener2`, and then inside the `usbConnectionStateChanged` callback, you could execute the code from Mr. Smith's answer to be sure that it's charging.

Comment: @user1615805, also regarding how to start an application in the background automatically, you can see [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3978232/119114), or [this one, too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5772279/119114).  This makes sure that as soon as the phone starts up, your listener can be registered.  Your app stays in the background.  Then, whenever USB is connected/disconnected, you get a callback via `usbConnectionStateChange()` and can take the opportunity to start or stop playing your sounds.

Comment: Could I omit the MySceen class since this is a background app? One class left, public class HelloWorld extends Application implements SystemListener2   
{}

Comment: @user1615805, correct.  If you don't planning on *showing* any UI, then you don't actually need to have any `Screen` subclasses.  One `Application` subclass should be enough.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work with a single class, but I tried pluggin it in and out it plays the sound, but only after 3 tries. Afer the 4th plug in, no sound plays. I've edited the original code

Comment: @user1615805, It sounds like something isn't getting cleaned up.  Are you sure you're not seeing exceptions thrown?  I'm not sure that you can use `Dialog.alert()` in a non-graphical application.  Maybe replace those with `println()` calls, or the `EventLogger`, to log the exceptions.  Also, I would probably keep `Player p` as a *member variable* in your class, so that when you call `p.stop()`, you know for sure that you're stopping the same player that started.  And, probably don't call `createPlayer()` unless the usb state is **connected**.

Comment: @user1615805, you might also need to play with whether or not you should call `createPlayer()` more than once (if USB is connected, then disconnected, then connected again).  You might need to `createPlayer()` once, hold the `Player` instance as a member variable, and then just call `start()` and `stop()` on that single instance.  Again, you'll have to experiment.

Comment: ok, will do, i'll post back soon if I can get it to work perfectly, thanks

Comment: yay got it to play perfectly now, tried in and out like 20 times and it plays every single time, although when I installed it at first, it gave me a java lang null exception error